# Fermi estimate for ice nucleation timescale

Tags: water, phase-transition, estimation, ice, fermi-problem

My friends in a [Cryo-EM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryo-electron_microscopy) lab freeze their very samples quickly, a process they call vitrification. The timescale for this process is milliseconds (from wikipedia):

> The production of amorphous ice hinges on the fast rate of cooling. Liquid water must be cooled to its glass transition temperature (about 136 K or −137 °C) in milliseconds to prevent the spontaneous nucleation of crystals.

To me, that seems slow. I suspected that the spontaneous nucleation of water should be much faster then milliseconds based off of the following (obviously erroneous argument): at neutral pH the protonation rate is about a millisecond but this exchange happens very frequently throughout the liquid and once a nucleation event starts it should proceeded exponentially.

Question: **What is a good [Fermi estimate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_problem) and explanation for the millisecond timescale of liquid to ice nucleation?**

Comment: Great question! Presumably as the liquid cools the nucleation rate changes, and a good answer will take that into account.